# Allowing customers using our site to pay direct to our Clients Sage Pay account

Tags: opayo, worldpay

We currently allow our clients to receive payments made via our online booking site, directly into their own Paypal account and then return back to our online booking site to complete and confirm the booking once payment has been successfully completed.

I would like to offer the same service for SagePay (and others e.g. Worldpay).  Can someone please point me in the right direction as I am struggling to connect with SagePay direct at the moment?

Thanks

Nigel